# Is it possible to pass a Proc into a function?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to implement Ruby's function composition operator `<<` into Crystal's proc. In Ruby it seems pretty straight forward.

```
  def << block
    proc { |*args| self.call( block.to_proc.call(*args) ) }
  end
end
```

I've tried to do something similar.

```
struct Proc
  def <<(&block)
    Proc.new { |*args, blk| call(block.call(*args, blk)) }
  end
end
```

I've tried testing it with a simple adder and suber function

```
def add(x : Int32)
  x + 1
end

def sub(x : Int32)
  x - 1
end
```

But, I'm getting this error. `Error: wrong number of arguments for 'Proc(Int32, Int32)#<<' (given 1, expected 0)`

I've also tried changing the `<<` to take in a proc but that also results in  `expected block type to be a function type, not Proc(*T, R)`

I'm kind of new to the language so I'm not too sure what knowledge I'm missing to understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `Proc` is underspecified. The `Proc` type is a generic type and needs to be instantiated with specific generic arguments that describe the types of its parameters and the return type.

You can see the same behaviour with a minimal example:

```
Proc.new { 1 } # Error: expected block type to be a function type, not Proc(*T, R)
```

Granted, the error message is not very telling.

---

A working example for what you try to achieve could look like this:

```
struct Proc
  def <<(block : Proc(*U, V)) forall U, V
    Proc(*T, V).new { |arg| call(block.call(arg)) }
  end
end

def add(x : Int32)
  x + 1
end
 
def sub(x : Int32)
  x - 1
end

x = ->add(Int32) << ->sub(Int32)
p! x.call(10)
```